# http post setEntity using robospice SpringAndroid

Tags: android, http, http-post, retrofit, robospice

I recently move to SpringAndroidSpice network lib from robospice, I want to replace this httpost set entity using SpringAndroidSpice. How can i do it.

```
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("childId", childId);

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
```

Comment: HI Sam did you found any solution for this, bcoz i'm also facing the same issue could you please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Nop, but i have moved from SpringAdroid to Retrofit. and retrofit can do this simply.